# MapboxGL Javascript API: displaying popup for all markers on map not working on multiple layers

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

I have multiple layers on my map, each one corresponding to a certain symbol (a Mapbox icon) and containing all the markers with that symbol. I want every marker to be clickable with its own popup. However,only the last layer that gets added allows the user to click on those markers and see the popup, while the previous layers get covered so the markers in those layers are not clickable.

Here's the JS Fiddle (most of the code is from the two examples on the website, and I'm trying to combine them together)

https://jsfiddle.net/wy5rdwzz/

I need this line of code to be able to filter the markers by toggling a list, and I need every single marker to be clickable.

```
"filter": ["==", "marker-symbol", symbol]
```

How would I go about making all the markers accessible (so that they can be clicked and a popup will show up), not just the ones in the last layer that gets added on?

Also, how would you go about displaying the name of each marker next to the corresponding marker, if each marker has its own layer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that you were never storing your layer ids. Each time you added a layer, you were overwriting `layerID` with the latest id. Thus, when you created your onclick & mousemove listeners, you were only adding these listeners to the most recent layer: `{ layers: [layerID] }`.

I've edited your jsfiddle ([here](https://jsfiddle.net/wy5rdwzz/1/)) to push each layer id into an array each time a layer is added: `{ layers: layerIdCollection }`.

Let me know if you have any questions :)

Comment: How can I add a new marker to an existing layer? If I use the same layerID, it overwrites that entire layer and makes all the other markers in the layer disappear from the map. However, if I use a different id, that marker would show up on the map but it won't be included in that layer so the toggling function wouldn't work on that marker. Any suggestions on how to solve this issue, since map.setLayoutProperty() only takes in a string and not an array?

Comment: It doesn't seem like mapbox provides a good way to add points to an existing layer. What I've done in the past is just add another layer to the parent source. I've had 1k+ layers on a single source and haven't experienced any performance issues.

You'll also have to add the onclick listener to layers added after the map is initialized.

Comment: I see, are you able to combine layers that you want together? For example, for the toggling functionality in the JS fiddle, would Mapbox GL allow you to combine a new marker's layer with an existing layer so that toggling would show/hide not just the markers in the existing layer but also the new marker? Or are there other ways that could make this work?

Comment: I don't believe they provide a method that allows you to merge layers. I would just use `setLayoutProperty  (layer, name, value)` on each of the layers you want to manipulate

Comment: So you're saying there's no way of changing a layer's id to match an existing id so that all the markers in those layers can be manipulated all at once? Since setLayoutProperty can't take in an array of layers, which would contain each of the layers I want to manipulate, i can't think of any other way to do the toggling unless all the id's of the markers are the same.

Comment: Just iterate through each layer id stored in your array and perform `setLayoutProperty` on each one.